# German equivalents of "hog all the credit"

Tags: expression

In conversation, I just said:

> Das ist wirklich schade. Ich hätte mich nämlich gern bei ihr für ihren guten Rat bedankt ... Immerhin hat sie wegen uns so viel durchgemacht und mich obendrein noch auf jede Menge tolle Geschäftsideen gebracht! **Den Erfolg** kann ich **mir** also nicht allein **auf die Fahne heften**.

Here I was talking about how a good part of the credit goes to her -- how I can't possibly hog all the credit. Alternatively, I might have said:

> **Den Erfolg** kann ich **mir** also nicht allein **als Verdienst** **anrechnen**.
>
> **Den Erfolg** **hab** ich **mir** also nicht allein **zuzuschreiben**.
>
> **Den Erfolg** **hab** ich **mir** also nicht allein **zu verdanken**.
>
> **Für den Erfolg** kann ich **mich** also nicht **bei mir** allein **bedanken**.

I'm wondering if any of my phrasings above works well enough? How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Comment: Those are all good but *nicht allein mir* is more idiomatic.

Comment: Instead of *auf die Fahne heften*, *an die Brust heften* is the better picture, as medals go there.

Comment: @Janka Ah, thanks. In the rapid flow of conversation, sometimes it doesn't come easily to me, as a self-taught non-native, to quickly figure out how best to connect multiple adverbs and pronouns in a row.

Comment: Topic first, important things as late as possible.

Answer (score 7):

German translations that work well are `das ganze Lob einheimsen` oder `die ganze Ehre einheimsen`.

Another one is `die ganzen Lorbeeren kassieren / ernten` (the latter is a bit more formal).

And it is rather `auf die Fahne schreiben` than `auf die Fahne heften`.

Answer (score 1):

I would have chosen:

> ich kann nicht den ganzen Erfolg für mich beanspruchen

(I can't claim all the success for myself), which I find more appropriate for every-day use without being colloquial (as *einheimsen* or *kassieren* are).